# Sql Server Profiler Free Tool

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, profiler

I need A free Sql 2008 R2 Profiler As I Can not Use Sql Server Included Sql Profiler for some reasons. If there are any free profiling tools or something like this - it will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn about [profiling background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187346.aspx), [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175481.aspx), traces and [Extended events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354.aspx) and in your case you will not need a profiler, since you'll be able to do all there tricks by proper querying the sql server itself.

Take a look also on [Dynamic Management Views and Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx)

And finally there is one free tool available [sqlexpressprofiler](http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/) and also here is [one more from Google code named AnjLab](https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/)

Some solutions provided by [Idera](http://www.idera.com/Content/Home.aspx)

Comment: I  need A tool Or something I was working with nhibernate before and there is a tool for that but i need a generic one because i have a security issue to profile database in my company

Answer (score 3):

To run traces *like* SQL Server Profiler, even with AnjLab's replacement, you still need server-side permissions to run it.

In SQL Server 2000, you had to be a member of the sysadmin

In SQL Server 2005, you can [GRANT ALTER TRACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx) to allow non-sysadmins to run either profiling tool

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use the included one, does it error? I never found anything which came close to the included one apart from AnjLab Profiler. The only annoyance with it is you can't export traces for tuning.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source SQL Profiler by AnjLab which I'm using regularly:

- [AnjLab SQLProfiler][1]

Answer (score 0):

Anjlab Sql Profiler was great, and still is if you can get your hands on the old free version.

Now there is [Datawizard SQL Performance Profiler](http://www.datawizard.com) which has a free trial, but is commercial.

Comment: Datawizard seems not to have a free trial anymore but a license cost is 'latte money'.