# Intercept request from my browser to a SQL Server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, request, toad, intercept

I'm developing an app where I need to do some request to the DB (SQLServer) of my ERP.

I'd like to intercept the SQL request that are sent to the DB when I ask something in the ERP (in the browser), so I can reproduce this request with my own application.

I looked at Toad for SQL server but don't see if what I want is possible

ps: I only have read access user to the DB

Thks for your help guys

Comment: SQL Server Profiler on the SQL Server machine? Seems like your best bet ....

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181091.aspx)** if you have a licence for it.

If you don't have it, there are some free SQL profilers. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111811/sql-server-profiler-free-tool) for a list.

I recommend you **[sqlprofiler](https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/)**. I have used it and was pretty easy to install and use if you know how to use SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: I have sql server profiler but it tells me that I don't have the right to access (can't alter trace) when I try to connect.

SQLprofiler is not free, I'm looking for a free soft (poor student :p)

Comment: BTW, if you are a student you might have access to a Microsoft licence from your university (At least in my uni at UK I have)..

Comment: I just checked and no sqlprofiler in my MSDNAA account (Ahh french universities :p)

Comment: Probably is not a standalone product. Check if you have SQL Server professional edition or higher.

Comment: I have this

Microsoft SQL Server Management studio    10.50.1600.1 


Outils clients Microsoft Analysis Service 10.50.1600.1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27073/discussion-between-cad-and-joris)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is [Gallium Data](https://www.galliumdata.com) -- it's a smart database proxy that will give you full access to incoming (and outgoing) traffic, and you can even change it if desired. And it's free.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).